# How to remove safe area when tableview is used?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, safearealayoutguide

I have simple `UITableView` inside `UIViewController`. Here is configurations and constraints I set:

```
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.insetsContentViewsToSafeArea = false
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

By doing this, I canceled safeArea in UITableView and set top, bottom constrains ignoring `safeAreaLayoutGuide`. Yes, it perfectly works when I scroll by table and safe area is ignored as I want. Here is image showing this:

[image]

But the problem is at the beginning when I don't start scrolling or touching table. It starts below safe area, not out of safe area. Here it is:

[image]

I don't want it to happen. I want my `UITableView`(or first `UITableViewCell`) from the uppermost point ignoring safe area. It seems `UITableView` ignores this even if I set constraints correctly. So, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to also set the `tableView`'s [`contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2902261-contentinsetadjustmentbehavior):

```
tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```